# Is there a way to reuse some of my code, like a function?

Tags: python, reusability, derivative

So i'm some what new to python and as an exercise, I tried to make a derivative calculator that is completely inclusive(not importing anything). But i don't know how to expand the code i wrote for the first term for an x amount of terms, So is there a way to apply the same code i wrote for the first term and apply it to all the other potential terms? maybe in the form of a function?

Here is the code i have written so far(sorry if it is messy, i am fairly new):

```
def pwr_rule(a, n):
    a = float(a)
    n = float(n)
    a = a*n
    n = n-1
    return a, n;

input_string = input("Enter coefficient, base and exp. seperated by comma ")
term1 = input_string.split(", ")
    #removes spaces, commas and quote. marks
a, x, n = [term1[i] for i in (0, 1, 2)]
    #a is coeff
    #x is base
    #n is exp.

a, n = pwr_rule(a, n)
while True:
    if (n == 1):
        print(str(int(a)) + x)
    elif (n > 1):
        print(str(int(a)) + x + '^' +str(int(n)))
    elif (n == 0):
        print(str(int(a)))
    r = 0
    r += 1
    if (r > 0):
        break
```

edit: im just now realizing that the variable, x, is redundant, just disregard it

Comment: It might be worth editing the title, I don't think it reflects the question very well. As aside, you don't need the parentheses in if statements, and `print(str(int(a)) + x + '^' +str(int(n)))` (why the call to `int()` ?) could be simplified to `f"{a}^{n}"`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you had a go at writing a function for this?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it definitely helped me out a bit.